# check if each of string is present in another however the order

Tags: java, string, compare

I would like to compare two strings (`str1` and `str2`) to know if all elements of my `str2` are contained by `str1`.

To be more specific, please look at the following example:

I have:

```
str1="1,3"
str2= "1,2,3,5"

if(str2.contains(str1)
    System.out.print("YES");
else 
    System.out.print("NO");
```

My console displays "NO". However, **1** and **3** are present in `str2`. Do you know how to know if each element of my `str1` is present in my `str2` however the order?

Comment: split -> List -> contains...

Comment: @YCF_L, split, but not to `List`. `List` cares about order, but OP's program should not.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  Either will work.  But Set does get rid of duplicates.

Comment: You need to be more precise.  Do want to treat each string as a CSV list?  Do you care about duplicates?  Does "1,2,3" contain "1,1,1"?

Comment: @WJS, if he cares about dupes, then he'll need a cardinality-aware set. Which is, strictly speaking, a `Map<E, Integer>`. Most collection libraries have one, and also with Java8 anyone can write their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try converting both CSV strings to sets, and then using `Set#containsAll` to check if one set contain the other:

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str1.split(",")));
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str2.split(",")));
if (set2.containsAll(set1)) {
    System.out.print("YES");
}
else {
    System.out.print("NO");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two general cases here:

1. You don't care about duplicates. Meaning that `1,2,3,4` does contains `1,3,3`.
2. You **do** care about duplicates. That means `1,3,4,5` contains `1,4`, but not `1,1,4`.

Given

```
String str1 = "1,3,3";
String str2 = "1,2,3,4,5";
```

---

For **first** case.

All you have to do is make two `Set`s, and ask "bigger" set if it `containsAll` elements from the "lesser" set:

```
Set<String> dict = Set.of(str2.split(","));
Set<String> input = Set.of(str1.split(","));

if (dict.containsAll(input)) {
  print("Contains");
}
else {
  print("Doesn't contain");
}
```

---

For **second** case

You can also use a set, but you also need to know the cardinality of each of the elements. That means you want a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Long> elementCardinality(String[] input) {
  return Arrays.stream(input)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(),
        Collectors.counting()));
}
```

And then for your two strings:

```
Map<String, Long> dict  = elementCardinality(str2.split(","));
Map<String, Long> input = elementCardinality(str1.split(","));

boolean containsAll = true;
for (Map.Entry<String,Long> entry : input.entrySet()) {
  Long dictCardinality = dict.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0L);
  if (!dictCardinality.equals(entry.getValue())) {
    containsAll = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (containsAll) {
  print("Contains");
}
else {
  print("Doesn't contain");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

S1="1,3" is the string, there are no elements in the string.

if(str2.contains(str1)) implies if "1,3" is present in S2 i.e. "1,2,3,5", which is not hence its returning false. I matches the complete string and not the character of string

You can convert the string to a list of character/Integer and check if all elements in that list are present in the string S2.

Code:

```
    String s1 = "1,2";
    String s2 = "1,2,3,4";
    String s3 = "1,5";
    List<String> s1List = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s1.split(",")));
    List<String> s2List = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s2.split(",")));
    System.out.println(s1List);
    if(s1List.stream().allMatch(s2List::contains))
        System.out.print("YES");
    else
        System.out.print("NO");

    List<String> s3List = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s3.split(",")));
    System.out.println(s3List);
    if(s3List.stream().allMatch(s2List::contains))
        System.out.print("YES");
    else
        System.out.print("NO");
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
YES
[1, 5]
NO
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  Try `s1= "1,2"; s2 = "11,22,3,4";`  I made the same mistake earlier.

Comment: I guess, in that case you will have to convert both strings to Lists.

Comment: You don't need a second array list after you used `Arrays.asList`. What you do need though is your code disregarding the order of elements, as OP asked for that as well.